# Why was this specific NAA flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer

I recently flagged an answer as Not an Answer, and thought that it was a pretty clear-cut case: [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset/22544091) is asking for a technical explanation of why you would use one C function rather than another. [This "answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096990/why-use-bzero-over-memset/22544091#22544091) contains a code block with no explanation, and the code in question makes no attempt to address why one or the other function is preferable - rather, it's a humorous snippet that redefines one function as the other (entire content of answer posted below for reference):

```
/* Have it anyway you like :-) */

#ifndef bzero
#define bzero(d,n) memset(d,0,n)
#endif
```

The six upvotes and the comment it's accrued suggest that people have found it funny, and although it seems clear this doesn't address the merits of the functions in question, my flag was declined with the following message:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I'm not claiming the answer is "technically inaccurate", I'm sure that it does what it appears to - it just seems to me that it makes no attempt to answer the question asked. It's got value as a loosely relevant comment, but does not meet the standard to be even a poor answer. Am I wrong?

Comment: That looks like a case where you should use the "Other" flag and explain what the situation is. The NAA flag should be used when you're flagging something that a moderator can tell at a glance is clearly not an attempt at an answer (e.g., "Thanks, this solved my problem.", or "I'm having the same problem, any solution?").

Comment: I'll keep that in mind - but am I supposed to assume, then, that NAA should only be used if the answer is so obviously not an answer that you don't even have to look at the question to tell that? It just seems like if anyone read the question, it would be clear that this didn't make an actual attempt to answer it. I'd have expected the "could be handled with standard flags" rejection if I'd submitted an "other" flag.

Comment: And I guess I just feel like if what you're saying is the true, that the NAA flag should only be used for "thanks"/"me too"/etc type non-answers, then the description of it in the flag dialog isn't a very good representation of what you want to see it used for. It says it should be used for answers that "should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether" -- which seems to go far beyond the type of comment-as-answer you're describing.

Comment: I'd say that answer deserves a Very Low Quality Flag.

Comment: Mods are janitors. If someone walked up to the blackboard and wrote down some random formulae as an answer to a physics question, should it be the professor who is tasked with judging the answer for correctness (+, -, or erasing it from the board depending), or do you call the janitor and ask them to judge and handle it appropriately?

Comment: Analogies aside, though, we're provided a "Not an Answer" flag to use on posts that do not attempt to answer a question. I'm getting lots of downvotes, but nobody seems to actually be asserting that the flag was technically wrong. I'm not sure what to take away from this, aside from the comment by @BilltheLizard.

Comment: *lots of downvotes*...you got 4...

Comment: You might find [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)  helpful

Comment: @rene, what from that post do you think offers help here? I've read it, and this isn't a case regarding a link-only or partial answer - 0% of the content in this post makes an attempt to answer the actual question.

Comment: I read the post I linked to as: Only use NAA flags if it has nothing to do with the question. In your example the answer is still in context with the question, maybe incorrect but it is not using jQuery. When that is the case NAA flags gets declined more easily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was the moderator who declined this. I'll try and explain my reasoning here.

I debated this flag quite a bit (which is in itself a bad sign for an NAA flag - most NAA flags are obviously correct from just a handful of keywords/phrases in just the answer itself). I had to read the question to make my decision, in the end the bit of the question that swung it for me was:

> *`bzero` is considered deprecated, and furthermore is a not a standard C function*. According to the manual, `memset` is preferred over `bzero` for this reason.  So why would you want to still use `bzero` over `memset`?

(Emphasis mine)

In my view the code was an attempt at answering that chunk of the question, that is to say it's answering the point that bzero is deprecated (could be removed) or might not exist at all.

It's a poor answer in my view, no doubt about it, but still an attempt to answer at least a reasonable subset of the question. That it had no text is not usually a reason to delete an answer in and of itself. The bottom line was that I felt there was no way I could delete the answer and not be reflecting a technical criticism of the content instead of a structural one. I would expect this to be handled via downvotes, not mod powers so declining made sense.

(Bootnote: I didn't expect this before becoming a mod, but flags on content I'm familiar with the language/tools are actually much harder to handle in most cases than ones where I know little/nothing about the topic)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. That's a much more nuanced reading of how this could possibly relate to the question than I had read into it, and I definitely see what you're saying about understanding the topic better leading to less of a clear cut case.