# Change the name and explanation on NAA flag

Tags: feature-request, not-an-answer

"Not an Answer" should be "Not an Attempt to Answer"

It currently states:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the
>   question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question,
>   or deleted altogether.

It is still confusing people on what qualifies as NAA and that moderators will take some action to migrate it to a comment or make a judgement call, which they will not.

I think it should read.

> Any attempt to answer the question no matter how poorly worded or
>   incorrect that could possibly be interpreted as an **attempt** at
>   answering should **NOT** be flagged with this flag.

There are still people posting asking why they have gotten flag banned for flagging things as NAA that could be argued as qualifying using the existing explanation which kind of proves the point it is unclear and or outdated given the extremely loose interpretation of *attempt to answer* that is in place now.

Comment: I like the idea of renaming the flag, but I don't agree with your proposed text change.

Comment: How about: `This was posted as an attempted answer, but is an update to the question, a comment, another question, or otherwise not an attempted answer. Flags should not be used to indicate low quality, short, or technically incorrect attempted answers. Instead use downvotes and delete votes.`

Comment: Related: [Merge the “Not An Answer” and “Very Low Quality” flags into one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318952/215552), in respect to doing away with NAA althogether, and [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/215552), which is practically a duplicate, but from several years ago (although I like to proposed wording: *This was posted as an answer, but it does not look like an attempt to answer a question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.*)

Comment: Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141210/should-the-not-an-answer-flag-description-be-clarified/141217#141217

Comment: Rename the flag altogether, because people will still see Not ... Answer and select that blindly.  Change it to something like "Has nothing to do with the question" or "Have you ever so much as in to be where its not" or some such.  A massive change to throw everybody off their game.

Comment: The problem with NAA isn't the wording, it's the inconsistent enforcement. Some people have a ridiculous standard for what constitutes an answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302113, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308441, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291605, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291605

Comment: I say we trash the flag entirely. Its useless. Everything is an answer on SO. Even a [black-and-white *question*](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35902052/1) has been [deemed an answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318829/1555990).

Comment: I'm afraid we will never be able to agree on what the "not an answer" flag means. We cannot even agree on what *spam* is. Apparently, some Meta denizens need to see a picture of spiced ham before they'll agree that an unsolicited, obviously off-topic post is spam. This is why we cannot have nice things.

Comment: Your new statement is really confusing. I read it a couple times and still don't understand it. After making such a change I assume there would be tons of confusion about what the **NAA** flag should be used for.

Answer (score 3):

#### Not an Answer -> Not an Attempt to Answer

Yes. Do this. Relabel the flag. The description can stay. This has needlessly wasted far too much time and effort on the part of flaggers, moderators, posters alike.

Comment: NAA technically already is the abbreviation for Not an Attempt to Answer. The only thing that would need to change to maintain the current (mis)interpretation of the flag is to change the label, not the abbreviation.

Comment: @Gimby, Brilliant, let's do that then.

Comment: But it doesn't really solve any problems to be honest. I'm more in favour of [this suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286364/424903) to specifically make it "Does not attempt to answer **this** question", because for Peet's sake that is the only thing that makes sense and leaves nothing to the imagination.

Comment: @Gimby, Frankly, I've raised a few flags and answered a few questions. I **still** get it wrong. And it's **only** to do with the label "Not an Answer" as opposed to "Not an Attempt to Answer". I can't expect much else from others. And, repeatedly, this is the only misconception I see on Meta relating to this flag. It'll solve the problem for me, likely for many others too.

Answer (score -1):

How about `Off Topic / Not an Answer` as the flag name? As I've learned more about the conventions on SO, I've come to understand that a major difference between non-NAA and NAA answers is that low quality non-NAA answers (unclear answers, undocumented code dumps, poorly written answers, and *incorrect* answers) are at least *on topic* for the question asked. Legitimate answers that do not merit a NAA flag and that are not obviously spam, rude, a comment, a new question, or a "thank you" have a clear connection with the question that can be perceived by reading it together with the question.

There is still the fact that non-attempts to answer the question like comments, new questions, and "thank you"s are at least minimally on topic to the question, so "Not an Answer" should still be part of the flag. Keeping NAA in the flag name would also help older users who have already mastered the concept of NAA and might be confused with seeing a completely renamed flag and wonder whether it is a new concept to be learned.

Comment: [*"Have you tried X?"* is now considered an attempt to answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317773/please-explain-why-this-qualifies-as-an-answer) and will be declined whereas it used to be solidly in the *comment* category. What is *off-topic* is no more objective than that being a comment or an attempt to answer.

Comment: "Have you tried X?" could be interpreted as an answer in which the answerer is proposing X as the solution. It's not really a "new question". A new question might be something like "Would John's solution work on a Mac too?" or "How about them Mets?".

Comment: And "Have you tried X" should probably be edited to say something like.  "9 times out of 10, X works for these problems"

Comment: ^ Not it should not. Suggesting to try X is not the same as stating that X almost always works

Comment: "Have you tried X?" is more equivalent to "The first thing I'd do is X, that usually either fixes it for me or gives me better information." (e.g. "Have you tried using the debugger?") Still, I personally tend to post such things as comments, if it works then I can post a detailed answer. If it doesn't, there's new information, and I can post a detailed answer.